# Connecting Two external monitors

Tags: display

I am currently using Acer TravelMate 6592 and I want to connect two external monitors to it, My Laptop does have both VGA and the other type (white connector)  but when I connect both of them, one external monitor goes   off.

How can I have both of them on with three different programs appearing on them including my Laptop screen without using external device.

Thanking you in advance..

Kind regards,

Tman

Answer (score 1):

From [TravelMate 6592/6592G Service Guide](http://tim.id.au/laptops/acer/travelmate%206592%206592g.pdf) (PDF):

> To enable the dual monitor feature of
> the notebook, first ensure that the
> second monitor is connected, then
> select Start, Control Panel, Display
> and click on Settings. Select the
> secondary monitor (2) icon in the
> display box and then click the check
> box Extend my windows desktop onto
> this monitor. Finally, click Apply to
> confirm the new settings and click OK
> to complete the process.

Hopefully then, on this screen you should see 3 display choices (your laptop's, and the two external displays).

Comment: I did this but it is not working, when I go to Settings, there it only shows two same Display 1 & 2 of which I can only select 'Extend my Windows desktop onto this monitor' check box once I have selected no 2 Display.

Comment: Hrm, I'm not sure what to do if only 1 of the 2 external displays shows up.  Is it the VGA or the DVI (white connector) that shows up?